# Proper template idiom (intuition)

Tags: c++, class, templates, member

I am trying to understand C++ template meta-programming in deeper concept. What I fail to understand is what a template really means. Specifically, what the idiom is for a templated class with static members. Take the following example:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Matrix {
  private:
    
  public:
    static constexpr Matrix<T> Identity(int,int);
    static constexpr Matrix<T> Zero(int,int);
    static constexpr Matrix<T> Null = Matrix();

    typdef value_type;

    Matrix();
    Matrix(int,int);
}
```

The static member functions of `Matrix` obviously construct typical matrices. My thoughts were that the way to think about the text (the idiom) `Matrix<T>::Identity` would be the ***identity matrix of a class with*** `value_type = T`.

### TL;DR

To restate, I believe that the template above generates a *set* of classes with respective static members `Matrix<T>::Identity` of their 'type'. This is in comparison to the other intuitive semantics of some `Matrix::Identity<T>()` which would be a Identity of type `T` for all matrices. Which is correct?

Comment: A template is a recipe.  When you do `Matrix<int>`, it takes your template and stamps out a version where it replaces all occurances of `T` with `int`.

Comment: i am not aware of this being called an idiom. Its like an ordinary class with static methods, just that from the template you can instantiate many different classes

Comment: `Matrix` is a class template. For a given `T`, `Matrix<T>` is a class. `Matrix<T>::Identity` is a static class function of the class `Matrix<T>` and `Matrix<T>::Null` is a static member of the class. `Matrix::Identity<T>` is not a thing, though it's possible to have templated members of non-templated classes and they would have that sort of syntax.

Comment: All template programming is not meta-programming.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm a big noob.

Comment: TY, edited the comment.

Comment: note: identity matrices are always square, so Identity should just have one parameter

Comment: @molbdnilo "not all template programming is meta programming"? Some template programming certainly is meta ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yeah, that's what I meant. And I call myself a programmer...

Comment: @hunter template meta programming refers to when you dive down into the turing complete pit that is c++ templates and drown.

Answer (score 0):

without any other condition, it is nothing different between `Matrix<T>::identity` and `Matrix::identity<T>`. it just looks like `someFunction<T>`. so there is not any idiom.

but in the other hand, a lot of practical problems make you choose the better one.

1. what's the `Matrix::identity<T>`? if `Matrix<T>` means a matrix class whose element has type of `T`, what is `Matrix` itself? it's a *class template*, so it can not have any member without instantiation. in this case, you should define an individual class (for example, named `MatrixUtility`), and use `MatrixUtility::identity<T>`. sounds noisy, right?
2. however, what about `Matrix::identity` (or `MatrixUtility::identity`)? usually the type `T` can be deduced in the context. for example:

```cpp
Matrix<int> a = MatrixUtility::identity(3, 3); // T=int is required in this context.
auto lambda = [](Matrix<double>){};
lambda(MatrixUtility::identity(2, 2)); // T=double is required in this context.
```

so there is a tricky way to implement it, by the auto-deduction of `operator T()`:

```cpp
struct Helper{
    template<typename T>
    operator Matrix<T>(){
        // construct and return
    };
    int w, h;
};

struct MatrixUtility{
    Helper identity(int w, int h){
        return Helper{ w, h };
    }
};
```

and in this case, `MatrixUtility` is actually necessary.

3. nonetheless, you need `MatrixUtility::identity<T>` as well because sometimes a monomorphism is required:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void foo(Matrix<T>);

auto a = MatrixUtility::identity(3, 3); // unexpected, a has type of Helper.
auto b = MatrixUtility::identity<int>(3, 3); // ok.
foo(MatrixUtility::identity(3, 3)); // ill-formed, T is not deducible.
foo(MatrixUtility::identity<int>(3, 3)); // well-formed.
```

finally, the implementation which you choose should rely on what you really need. you need a polymorphism, then choose `MatrixUtility::identity`; you need the most simplification, then choose `Matrix<T>::identity`; rather than comply with a fixed idiom.